# Json schema relative $ref to current "id"

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have searched SO and JSON schema documentation for a few days now, but I'm struggling to get my JSON Schema references to work across multiple files in the same directory.

My root schema would be an `oneOf` object:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "id": "http://localhost/json-editor/schema/function.json",
  "title": "Function",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "./fn_md5.json"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "fn_sha1.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now after reading the docs and most questions here, I'd assume both `./fn_md5.json` and `fn_sha1.json` would be resolved to `http://localhost/json-editor/schema/fn_....json` (where the `...` represents their respective name, of course). However, the resolver keeps looking into `http://localhost/json-editor/fn_....json`, which appears to be relative to the application's url ([JDorn's JSON Editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) running at my http://localhost/json-editor/).

Am I understanding the schema and `id` wrong, or could it be an error with the editor's URL resolver?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be resolved as you say. It seems a problem with the resolver.

Answer (score -1):

for find the relative references you need use $id like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "id": "http://localhost/json-editor/schema/function.json",
  "$id":"https://www.baseurl.com/"
  "title": "Function",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$id": "./fn_md5.json"
    },
    {
      "$id": "fn_sha1.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.2.4